# XML to SQL Tables without explicit column names

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to insert data into SQL using XML. I've managed to figure out the insert operation like so.

```
create table #testTable (name varchar(50), designation varchar(50));

declare @xmldata as xml

set @xmldata = '<?xml version="1.0"?>

<Employees>

<Employee name="John" designation="SE"></Employee>

<Employee name="Adam" designation="ASE"></Employee>

</Employees>'

insert into #testTable

select 

  r.value('@name', 'varchar(50)'),

  r.value('@designation', 'varchar(50)')

from @xmldata.nodes('/Employees/Employee') t(r)
```

Using this method, I am required to pre-specify the column names when I use the value method manually.

What I want is a method to run this query without specifying the columns explicitly in the value() method and get a table with the XML attributes as the column names and the values as the data. I am willing to convert this to typed XML if it gets the job done. Assume that the xml columns will always conform to my existing table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not use some kind of external tool to do it, like a small C# application? It's certainly possible to do it using pure T-SQL, but it's just more difficult that way :) Or is this going to be a part of a stored procedure or something?

Comment: I was planning this out as a SP which accepts XML input. I'm sorry about the bad code. On a mobile device. Will correct it soon.

Comment: I don't get what you need here. You have an "existing table" with columns that is a match to the XML. Then you know what columns to expect so why don't you want to type the attribute names in the `value` function?

Comment: I am assuming there would be a performance hit if I get an XML with only some attributes populated. Is there a more optimal way to do it by selecting just the columns which are present in the XML? I would be dealing with around 200+ attributes. I figured out a way to recreate the query in the question as a dynamic query for now.

Comment: 200 attributes per Employee? Thats a lot. The query plan will be huge. Limiting the number of attributes to query may very well be a good thing. But on the other hand you need to shred the entire XML to find a unique list of attribute names in order to build the query dynamically. You have to test on your data to see if the large single query is faster or slower than parsing the XML to build the query dynamically. Another option could be to extract a name-value list from the XML to a temp table and then do a pivot over that result set. The pivot query would then have all the 200 columns.